# Nextjs does not render server side the default jsx of a boolean state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a simple nextjs page for the rendering of a `Post`. Everything run fine and nextjs render the complete page server side for a perfect SEO experience. However I wanted to add an edition mode using a boolean state:

```
const PostPage: NextPage = () => {
  const [editionMode, setEditionMode] = React.useState(false)

  return (
    <MainLayout>
     {editionMode ? <EditPostForm /> : <Post />}
    </MainLayout>
)
```

Sadly with this logic, nextjs doesn't render server side the `<Post />`.

So I know I could just remove this condition, always render the `<Post />` and put the `<EditPostForm />` into a modal or simply add a new endpoint like `/posts/:postId/edit`, but I wanted to know if there was just a simpler way to handle this case with a simple boolean value so that nextjs still server side render the default one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate SSR, you should use the [`getServerSideProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/rendering/server-side-rendering) to provide the server side render props.

And your useState's default value should get powered by the props.

```
const PostPage: NextPage = ({ data }) => {
  const [editionMode, setEditionMode] = React.useState(data.editMode)

  return (
    <MainLayout>
     {editionMode ? <EditPostForm /> : <Post />}
    </MainLayout>
);

// This gets called on every request
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  // Pass data to the page via props
  return { props: { data: { editMode: false } } };
}
```

I am curious about how your state becomes `true` to return the EditionMode component.

Comment: You are right, if I pass a dummy `edition` boolean from the `getServerSideProps` it's working. Using a simple button that `setEditionMode(true)` does the trick.